# Multiline Text View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How to set `Text` View to display text in multiple lines? By default it's 1 line.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
         Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse est leo, vehicula eu eleifend non, auctor ut arcu")
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can set lineLimit to nil for multiple lines.

```
struct ContentView : View {
        var body: some View {
             Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse est leo, vehicula eu eleifend non, auctor ut arcu")
              .lineLimit(nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work on Xcode 11.2

Comment: @Pacu Try to use this:
    ```Text("Ingredients: Avocado, Almond Butter, Bread")
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)```

Comment: working on 11.4 and 11.5-beta

Comment: @JonasDeichelmann suggested code worked for me on Xcode 11.6

Comment: Ensure that the `Text` is inside a container that has a known width

Answer (score 178):

You can use the answer from comments, thx to https://stackoverflow.com/users/8642838/jonas-deichelmann

```
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

Comment: RIP lineLimit function, does not  work in Xcode 11.3.

Comment: @joey Try to use this:
```Text("Ingredients: Avocado, Almond Butter, Bread")
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)```

Comment: .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) worked for me. Thank you @JonasDeichelmann

Comment: lineLimit doesn't work for me but this one worked.
Thanks for sharing this solution

Comment: This works for me! What I do not really understand though is why I don't have to always do this. E.g. I have two `Text`s that should wrap lines below each other in a `VStack`. It's only needed for the first one. For the second one I don't have to do anything. Is this a bug or a feature? (Sidenote: both `Text`s are also inside a `Group` on that I set `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)` for text alignment)