# SwiftUI text cropping issues in List Section

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Does anyone have a solution to this? It also does this in the Simulator. I have included screenshots from the preview.

Basically, you put a multiline text, it gets cropped after the second line. You add some more words, it does use a third line, you remove those words and it no longer crops the text.

```
struct SWSettingsContactsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("Add your contacts so you can quickly and easily call them from your dashboard.")
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the original text:

[image: Original text, cropped]

Then I added some words:

[image: Added some words, no longer cropped]

And then I removed them again:
[image: Removed the words, still no longer cropped]

Didn't change a letter of code.

And this is what it looks like in the simulator:

[image]

This is in Xcode 13.0

Comment: You should better add your codes.

Comment: The code is in the screenshots. There is nearly no code. But ok, I added it

Comment: I think this might solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558118/multiline-text-view-in-swiftui